# Find specifc name with cypress and react to then press button

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have this code inside my react component:

```
return (
    <div className="col">
      <div className="card border-secondary mb-3 text-center">
        <div className="card-header"> 
          <h5 data-cy='topicName' className="col-md"> {topicName} </h5> 
          <span> Rol: {capitalize(author)} </span>
        </div>
        
        <div className="card-body text-secondary">
          <p className="card-text">Última actualización: 16/06/2022</p>
        <div className="">                
        </div>
        </div>
      
        <div className="card-footer bg-transparent">
          <Link to='/responses' >
            <button data-cy='accederResponses' className="btn btn-outline-info " onClick={()=> onSetTopic(topicName, workspace_id, author, topicId)}>Acceder</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>              
  );
```

i want to load the page in cypress, and click() in the 'Acceder' button, but just in the card with the name 'CA2'.

[image]

but i don't know how.
now i have this in my test:

```
describe("LOAD OK", function() {
    it("should load without crashing", function() {
      cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
      cy.contains('[data-cy="topicName"]', 'CA2');
      cy.get('[data-cy="accederResponses"]').click(); //the button in the card 'CA2'
    }); 
   
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML sample is malformed, I would assume the `.card-body` is (or should be) like the following, as it's semantically correct.

```html
<div className="card-body text-secondary">
  <p className="card-text">Última actualización: 16/06/2022</p>
</div>
```

In this case the test is easiest like this:

```js
cy.contains('[data-cy="topicName"]', 'CA2')
  .closest('.card')
  .find('[data-cy="accederResponses"]')
  .click()
```

`.closest(selector)` is an **ancester** search, that is it goes **up** the DOM tree looking for the nearest `selector`.

`.find(selector)` is a **descendent** search, it goes **down** the DOM tree looking for `selector`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
describe("LOAD OK", function() {
  it("should load without crashing", function() {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
    cy.contains('[data-cy="topicName"]', 'CA2')
      .closest('.card-footer')
      .find('[data-cy="accederResponses"]')
      .click();
  });
});
```